# Has someone managed to implement a LinkedIn login with Firebase on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, linkedin-api, firebase-authentication

I'm currently building an app and I would like people to be able to sign up with their LinkedIn account.

I'm using Firebase for the back-end and LinkedIn isn't currently supported by the FirebaseAuth framework.

I know Firebase allows Custom Auth System but even after [reading the doc about this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/custom-auth), I still struggle to understand how I can plug LinkedIn there and what the so-called authentification server is.

Has someone managed to make this work?

Thanks in advance for your inputs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Firebase Authentication supports only four federated Identity Providers out of the box: Google, Facebook, Twitter and GitHub.

For every other provider you have to use [custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens) (you will need an external Webservice).

You can read more [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/10/authenticate-your-firebase-users-with.html) for a full example (the link is for Instagram but it will also work for LinkedIn as they say).

Comment: There are several others with built-in support now (including Microsoft and Yahoo), but still no LinkedIn.

Answer (score 16):

See this example in official Firebase repo: [Use LinkedIn Sign In with Firebase](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/Node-1st-gen/linkedin-auth)

> In this sample we use OAuth 2.0 based authentication to get LinkedIn
> user information then create a Firebase Custom Token (using the
> LinkedIn user ID).

Answer (score 11):

Looks like the post is few years old, so not sure if you have found the solution, but for the benefit of everyone. in the current version of firebase, this is how I was able to use LinkedIn.

```js
export function signUpWithLinkedIn() {
    return auth
        .setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
        .then(()=>{
            const provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('linkedin.com');
            provider.addScope('r_emailaddress');
            provider.addScope('r_liteprofile');
            auth
                .signInWithPopup(provider)
                .then(result=>{
                    console.group('LinkedIn');
                    console.log(result);
                    console.groupEnd();
                    return result;
                })
                .catch(error=>{
                    console.group('LinkedIn - Error');
                    console.log(error)
                    console.groupEnd();
                    throw error;
                });

        });
}
```

Comment: I was wondering if you could give more descriptions

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying this for a long time, and finally managed to do it.

I assume you have your client id and secret

Here is how I did it

1. Open postman or something you can send requests to GCP
2. [https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v2/projects/${project-id}/defaultSupportedIdpConfigs?idpId=linkedin.com](https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v2/projects/$%7Bproject-id%7D/defaultSupportedIdpConfigs?idpId=linkedin.com) --- add your project id here
3. Get access token from GCP by running (gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)
4. Add that to Authorization header {"Authorization": "Bearer ${token}"}
5. Add this json body

   {
   "name": "projects/${project-id}/defaultSupportedIdpConfigs/linkedin.com",
   "enabled": true,
   "clientId": "${clientId}",
   "clientSecret": "${clientSecret}"
   }

Send the request and you are done, go to gcp (not firebase) console, open identity platform, you will see linkedin.com provider

In order to use it inside your app just do:

```
async function handleLinkedinSignIn() {
    const provider = new OAuthProvider("linkedin.com");
    provider.addScope("r_liteprofile");
    provider.addScope("r_emailaddress");
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
}
```

Everything will be handled by firebase auth automatically