# Running into auth/operation-not-allowed in firebase auth when using a LinkedIn Provider

Tags: firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication, linkedin-api

I'm using this code snippet found on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63393721/12422281) to sign in using a LinkedIn provider:

```
export function signUpWithLinkedIn() {
    return auth
        .setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
        .then(()=>{
            const provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('linkedin.com');
            provider.addScope('r_emailaddress');
            provider.addScope('r_liteprofile');
            auth
                .signInWithPopup(provider)
                .then(result=>{
                    console.group('LinkedIn');
                    console.log(result);
                    console.groupEnd();
                    return result;
                })
                .catch(error=>{
                    console.group('LinkedIn - Error');
                    console.log(error)
                    console.groupEnd();
                    throw error;
                });

        });
}
```

I'm getting the error "auth/operation-not-allowed", "The identity provider configuration is not found." Others who have run into this error are using natively supported login providers such as Google or Facebook and enabling those providers on the Firebase console avoids this error. Any ideas as to how to accomplish something similar with LinkedIn?

Answer (score 2):

To use LinkedIn login for your Firebase project you first need to programmatically configure LinkedIn OAuth as identity provider for Firebase Authentication. See documentation on how to configure OAuth on [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/provisioning/configure-oauth).

For my project I followed the following steps:

**Step 1:**
Create node.js file in my project folder and copy paste the code provided by Firebase documentation to obtain access to my Firebase project:

```
const googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'];

async function getAccessToken() {
    const serviceAccount = require('/path/to/service_account_key.json');
    const jwtClient = new googleAuth.JWT(
        serviceAccount.client_email,
        null,
        serviceAccount.private_key,
        SCOPES,
        null
    );
    return jwtClient.authorize().then((tokens) => tokens.access_token);
}
```

**Step 2:**
In the function above you need to retrieve your private_key and client_email by going to your Firebase console and click on project settings > service accounts. A file will be downloaded and you can add it to a secure location. Make sure the path is correct

**Step 3:**
Go to LinkedIn and follow the steps to create an APP. After completing this you will be able to get client ID and secret code. In your auth settings please set your call back url to firebase. Example:

```
Authorized redirect URLs for your app: https://your-project-id.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler
```

**Step 4:**
Go back to your node.js file and copy paste the configuration code for LinkedIn below your getAccessFunction (see documentation):

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const GCIP_API_BASE = 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v2';

async function addIdpConfig(projectId, accessToken, idpId, clientId, clientSecret) {
    const uri = `${GCIP_API_BASE}/projects/${projectId}/defaultSupportedIdpConfigs?idpId=${idpId}`;
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: `projects/${projectId}/defaultSupportedIdpConfigs/${idpId}`,
            enabled: true,
            clientId: clientId,
            clientSecret: clientSecret,
        }),
    };
    return fetch(uri, options).then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        } else if (response.status == 409) {
            throw new Error('IdP configuration already exists. Update it instead.');
        } else {
            throw new Error('Server error.');
        }
    });
}

(async () => {
    const projectId = 'your-firebase-project-id';
    const accessToken = await getAccessToken();
    const idpId = 'linkedin.com';
    const clientId = 'your-linkedin-client-id';
    const clientSecret = 'your-linkedin-client-secret';
    try {
        await addIdpConfig(projectId, accessToken, idpId, clientId, clientSecret);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
})().catch(console.error);
```

**Step 5:**
Run your node.js file in your terminal. You will receive a message that the configuration has been added. To make sure it worked you can run the node file again and should receive a message that the configuration already exists.

**Step 6:**
Create component to display LinkedIn button

```
import { signUpWithLinkedIn } from "../../auth/LinkedInAuth";

const LinkedInLogin = () => {
    return (
        <div onClick={() => signUpWithLinkedIn()} >
            <div type="submit" style={{ height: "40px", width: "215px" }}>
                <img
                    style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
                    src={
                        "https://taggbox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Signin-with-LinkedIn.png"
                    }
                    alt={"LinkedIn authentification"}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default LinkedInLogin
```

Step 7:
Create the authAction for LinkedIn

```
import {auth, firebase} from "../../../lib/db"

export function signUpWithLinkedIn() {
    return auth
    .setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
    .then(()=>{
        const provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('linkedin.com');
        provider.addScope('r_emailaddress');
        provider.addScope('r_liteprofile');
        auth
            .signInWithPopup(provider)
            .then(result=>{
                console.group('LinkedIn');
                console.log(result);
                console.groupEnd();
                return result;
            })
            .catch(error=>{
                console.group('LinkedIn - Error');
                console.log(error)
                console.groupEnd();
                throw error;
            });

    }); 
}
```

That is it! I have any questions let me know.

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To use a custom Auth solution requires an intermediate service such as Cloud Functions or a dedicated server to interact with the OAuth provider. The reason is OAuth providers require a custom App that represents your own App's requirements on their infrastructure, typically this is only Auth permissions. This process will give you a secret key that you must store in a secure environment so you can authorize requests for your app.

Within your Auth providers' App will be an Auth section that will ask for a redirect URL, this is used as a call back on successful login to the server which will then generate the sufficient Tokens for your client app.

To setup with Firebase Cloud Functions:

1. If you have not already, you will need to create a LinkedIn app in the [LinkedIn Developers website](https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps/).
2. Add the URL `https://<application-id>.firebaseapp.com/popup.html` to the **OAuth 2.0 > Authorized Redirect URLs** of your LinkedIn app.
3. Copy the Client ID and Client Secret of your LinkedIn app and use them to set the `linkedin.client_id` and `linkedin.client_secret` Google Cloud environment variables. For this run a console command in the project like so:

```
firebase functions:config:set linkedin.client_id="yourClientID" linkedin.client_secret="yourClientSecret"
```

Inside your Cloud Functions, you will need a working script that acts as the handshake client

- Source: [Cloud Functions example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/linkedin-auth/functions/index.js)

I suggest looking at this full project as Custom OAuth solutions are more involved: [**LinkedIn with Firebase**](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/linkedin-auth)

Comment: I've been examining this codebase. One thing I'm confused about is where the '/redirect' page is defined. In popup.html, the page pushes to a '/redirect' url which is an unknown route.

Comment: it gets sent to the OAuth provider so when you complete login, it'll redirect the user back to your site

Comment: Right, but right now it's triggering my unknown route fallback. I changed firebase.json to redirect the route to call the function, but maybe it's because I'm testing on local host? I'm working on deploying the site. Do the firebase functions not work without the hosting?

Comment: Cloud Functions do not require hosting, but you can set up rewrites to cloud functions from hosting.