How to connect firebase authentication to linkedin with flutter?
I'm trying to connect my linked authentication to firebase but couldn't able to do that.
I've succesfully authenticated with linkedin using linkedin_login plugin and received accessToken and profile data. With accessToken I have tried to authenticate to firebase using signInWithCredential() of firebase_auth plugin but getting error [firebase_auth/channel-error] "dev.flutter.pigeon.firebase_auth_platform_interface.FirebaseAuthHostApi.signInWithCredential"..
class LinkedInAuthSample extends StatelessWidget {
  const LinkedInAuthSample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: LinkedInButtonStandardWidget(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute<void>(
                builder: (final BuildContext _) => LinkedinAuthPage(
                  onLinkedAuth: (AuthLinkedUser linkedUser) {
                    debugPrint(
                        "LINkED USER ===========>${linkedUser.toJson()}");
                    linkedInAuthToFirebase(linkedUser);
                  },
                ),
                fullscreenDialog: true,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
// Here I'm trying to my linkedin auth to firebase.
linkedInAuthToFirebase(AuthLinkedUser linkedUser) async {
    try {
      final AuthCredential credential = AuthCredential(
          accessToken: linkedUser.accessToken,
          providerId: 'linkedin.com',
          signInMethod: 'password');

      final userCredentialData =
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("Authentication failed: $e");
    }
  }
}

Linkedin Authentication page :

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:linkedin_login/linkedin_login.dart';
import 'package:whatisyoura/modules/login/models/linked_user.dart';

const String redirectUrl =
    "https://www.linkedin.com/developers/tools/oauth/redirect";
const String clientId = '8....';
const String clientSecret = 'WP.....';

class LinkedinAuthPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool destroySession;
  final Function(AuthLinkedUser linkedUser) onLinkedAuth;
  const LinkedinAuthPage(
      {super.key, this.destroySession = false, required this.onLinkedAuth});

  @override
  State<LinkedinAuthPage> createState() => _LinkedinAuthPageState();
}

class _LinkedinAuthPageState extends State<LinkedinAuthPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LinkedInUserWidget(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('OAuth User'),
      ),
      destroySession: widget.destroySession,
      redirectUrl: redirectUrl,
      clientId: clientId,
      clientSecret: clientSecret,
      onError: (final UserFailedAction e) {
        debugPrint('Error: ${e.toString()}');
        debugPrint('Error: ${e.stackTrace.toString()}');
        widget.onLinkedAuth(AuthLinkedUser(
            accessToken: null,
            firstName: null,
            lastName: null,
            email: null,
            profileImageUrl: null,
            exception: e.exception));
      },
      onGetUserProfile: (final UserSucceededAction linkedInUser) {
        
        var user = AuthLinkedUser(
          firstName: linkedInUser.user.givenName,
          lastName: linkedInUser.user.familyName,
          email: linkedInUser.user.email,
          profileImageUrl: linkedInUser.user.picture,
          accessToken: linkedInUser.user.token.accessToken,
        );
        widget.onLinkedAuth(user);

        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
    );
  }
}


Look, there is no Provider for linked in firebase authentication's signin method:


Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44244134/209103?

Firebase doe not have Linkedin support yet. SO, in the mean time, you could use customToken function to use custom auth provider with firebase
Example:
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCustomToken(token)

For more info, Authenticate with Firebase Using a Custom Authentication System

Is there any other solutions? because I've tried it and it needs cloud function to create custom token and cloud function need paid subscription.
